# Filter int, float and character from a text file in a Shell Script

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a text file,  which contains data like this. 
Below output generated from `du - sh /home/*`

```
1.5G user1
2.5G user2
```

And so on...

Now if I want that those files size be stored in an array and compared to 5 GB if the user is consuming more than 5 Gb. What can I do?

The du command shows the usage of each folder in home directory.  So if i want myself to be notified that some user is consuming more than 5 GB.  Because there is a long list of users.  It will be tedious to identify each user's disk usage.  I want a shell script to identify the usage for each directory in home. And then I will put mail function to notify myself for exceeded limits.

Note : Don't want to implement quota as I just want to monitor the usage.

Comment: Compare to what? What is the expected output? What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: Multi-user systems have quite robust ways to handle such things. I can recommend trying `man -k quota` and do some reading.

Comment: I don't want to implement quota as some users might need a large storage. I just want to monitor the usage.

Comment: Why don't you make life easy for yourself by dropping the `h` switch from `du` - it's for human readable after all, and you seem to want a script to read it. Perhaps you should use `du - s` ? Apologies if that's not within your control.

Comment: Just create a very large quota (like, the size of the filesystem).  It will be much easier to have the filesystem keep track of disk usage for you rather than re-calculating it all of the time with `du`.

Comment: That's what i did.  du - sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `du`'s `-t` (`--threshold`) option to specify you only want to know about directories with more than a certain amount of data in them:

```
$ du -sh -t 5G /home/*
```

If you're picky about precisely how big a gigabyte is, note that `5G` uses multiples of 1024; you may prefer `-t 5GB` for multiples of 1000, or even `-t 5000M` to mix them.

For lots of users, you're probably better off writing that using `-d 1` instead of `-s` to avoid the shell having to expand the `*` into a very long list:

```
$ du -h -d 1 -t 5G /home/
```

Comment: du's the -t option (--threshold) doesn't come by default in old Linux distros. But after upgrading this is the best option.